# IAM Policy to create a single ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How can I create a policy that will allow a single user in a group to create a single ec2 instance in a particular VPC and AZ. and it can be destroyed by the same user or destroyed when idle for more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

AWS does not provide either of your requirements, certainly not as an IAM policy.

- AWS does not track how many instances a specific user has created
- AWS will not terminate instances for you after a set period of time

You can create an IAM policy that will limit creation to a single region/AZ, but you can't limit the number of instances that user has created that are running simultaneously.  You could create an artificial limit by creating a /28 subnet (the smallest AWS allows), limiting the profile to creating/destroying in that subnet, which would allow a max of 14 instances at any one time, but that's still not what you want.

Also, AWS has no idea what your instance is doing at any time, and thus cannot tell if a running instance is "idle."  An instance with no running user-level processes is still using CPU (which is visible to AWS CloudWatch) for system processes.  And there's certainly no IAM policy type for "terminate my instances for me on an arbitrary measurement."

You will have to create your own solution.  One alternative might be to create a Lambda function which can create at most one running instance at a time (tracked perhaps by a tag or security group membership), and give your user an IAM policy to execute the Lambda function, but you will still have to come up with a way to decide if an instance is "idle" if you want to terminate automatically based on that.

Comment: Your lambda idea...nice hack! :)

Comment: @EEAA Thanks.  I work on infrastructure, so I see making Lambda functions for discrete tasks that require IAM privileges as generally a much better alternative than giving our developers those privileges directly.  It makes their lives simpler and makes me less worried that they will accidentally destroy stuff.

Comment: Cool, do you have a specific suggestion on how to do this? Or some documentation regarding a similar project?